# How do i pass user input values from html in Active Choice reference parameter to "Execute shell" step in jenkins freestyle job?

Tags: jenkins

Let's say, i have active choice reference input where i get user input with following html-code:

`<input name='value' class='setting-input' type='text' value="${NUMBER}" placeholder='number'>$NUMBER</input>`

But after that i add "execute shell" step with following code:

`echo "${NUMBER}"`

It returns nothing

If i add, for example
`echo "${ACTIVE_CHOICE_REFERENCE_PARAM_NAME}"`

It returns the name of active choice parameter. How can i return actual user html input? And i need to use more, than one input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this html code in the Active Reactive Reference section:

```html
return """<input type="text" class="setting-input" name="value">"""
```

Pipeline script:

```java
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo "${NUMBER}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: But your answer slightly doesn't help:
1. You mention only step in pipeline (i need for fresstyle job) and this step dosen't even call for shell.
2. With returning of multiple different inputs (like 2-3) it either will return nothing or only the first input value.

Comment: I will change my answer to include freestyle job. 2nd I didn't understand, what do you mean by different inputs. Please change your question accordingly to include some example

Comment: For example, if parameter has  
<input name='value' class='setting-input' type='text' value="${NUMBER1}" placeholder='number'>$NUMBER1</input>
<input name='value' class='setting-input' type='text' value="${NUMBER2}" placeholder='number'>$NUMBER2</input>

In this case, so far, i've managed to get only NUMBER1.